# how to print exception stack trace in aws cloud logs

Tags: python-3.x, exception, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using AWS lambda to execute code base.

Running aws lambda and watching aws cloudeatch logs, so only last traceback is printing.

i need traceback as it is printing in local python run.

```
class E(Exception):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            print(args)
        for kw in kwargs:
            print(kw)


class A:

    def a(self):
        try:
            x = 1 / 0
        except Exception as e:
            raise E("error") from e


def handler(event, context):
    try:
        A().a()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        raise e


handler(None, None)
```

Output :

```
error
[ERROR] E: error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda-function.py", line 46, in handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/lambda-function.py", line 43, in handler
    A().a()
  File "/var/task/lambda-function.py", line 38, in a
    raise E("error") from e
```